Stripe Payment Fields Not Appearing / Hangs Consistently Trying to Load
We are experiencing a new issue with Stripes integration on a WordPress site that uses Payment Plugins for the integration.  Over the past week, the Stripe js will routinely fail to load and just hang without ever presenting the credit card fields to enter.  We've tried everything from exploring the console errors, disabling all caching and CLoudflare, etc.  No matter what we try, we can briefly get them to come back, then within minutes they will stop appearing again.  This is making it so no one can check out on our site and we're losing orders by the second.
I'm not experienced enough of a developer to do more than this basic troubleshooting and the Payment Plugins support is only providing vague answers.
Curious if anyone here is available for hire/consult fee to help us look at the issue and troubleshoot it and get some skilled eyes on what could be occurring and help to resolve.  Ready to pay top dollar for a Stripe dev expert to lend a hand.
Have reset and reinstalled the plugins, reverted to backups of weeks ago when everything worked fine, but nothing works. live site still routinely will not load Stripe payment fields, and just hangs.  Console errors are vague.  No code changes on our end yet this just started occurring around June 11th, which seems to coincide with dates that Stripe started making changes to their API with Link and other features.  Coincidence?
Need an expert to help us take a look.

Sound best to reach out to the plugin developer/maintainer
